# declare a NSMutablearray of uiimages globally

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, global

I want to declare a global array so I can use this in all methods and every where in my app. I have two buttons which 1 shows the next image in the array and the other button shows the previous image shown. I want both buttons to use the same array.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
                          initWithObjects:@"Americans.png",
                                          @"Approach.png",
                                          @"Arianny.png",
                                          @"Atoms.png",
                                          @"Australia.png",nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dispatch_once to allocate a static object:

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
static NSMutableArray * images;
dispatch_once(&once, ^ { images = /*blah*/; });
```

Generally you would wrap this in a function or a class method of a utility class.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481201/how-to-make-a-global-array). I'd suggest going with putting it in your `AppDelegate` or creating a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like).

Comment: Yep, anchor the array in your app delegate or make it a singleton.